# Can two model use same table in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a table of categories with is_parent as its foreign key link with categories id in the same table. now I want to create relationship category hasMany subcategory and subcategory belongs to a category.
so that I can access as eloquent. how do I do that?

Here is my table structure:

```php
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('category_name');
    $table->text('category_description')->nullabale();
    $table->string('category_image');
    $table->boolean('category_status');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->boolean('is_parent');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->index('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 models for the same table, but in your case you don't need to.

Here is how you do the parent > child relationship:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
   ...
});
```

And for the model content:

```
class Category extends Model{
  ...
     public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','parent_id');
     }
     public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id');
     }
}
```

now to access the children of a category:

```
$category = App\Category::find(1);
$subCategories = $category->children;
```

the advantage of this method is you don't need to have 2 separate tables, one for the `category`, and one for the `sub-categories`, or 2 models, just one table, one model